# What is meaning of 'can only concatenate str (not "int") to str?'

Tags: python

I want to call 70 threads in my code as you can see to get html content :

```
def run_the_command(args):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        "Driver={SQL Server};"
        "Server=.;"
        "Database=test;"
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    )
    r = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/?page=" + args)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    table = soup.find("table", class_="cmc-table")
    for row in table.tbody.find_all("tr"):
        # Find all data for each column
        columns = row.find_all("td")
        link = "https://coinmarketcap.com" + columns[2].a["href"]

        r2 = requests.get(link)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "lxml")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        sql = "insert into coins(price,submitdate,name) values(?,?,?)"

        val = [
            (
                soup2.select_one('[class^="priceValue"]').text,
                datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                link,
            )
        ]

        cursor.executemany(sql, val)

        conn.commit()


try:

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        threads = []
        for i in range(70):
            t = threading.Thread(target=run_the_command, args=(i + 1,))
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
```

But I get this error :

```
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\e.akbar\Desktop\Crypto\gettable.py", line 14, in run_the_command
  File "c:\Users\e.akbar\Desktop\Crypto\gettable.py", line 14, in run_the_command
  File "c:\Users\e.akbar\Desktop\Crypto\gettable.py", line 14, in run_the_command
    r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/?page='+args)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
    r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/?page='+args)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
    r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/?page='+args)
    r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/?page='+args)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
    r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/?page='+args)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I am new in python

Comment: I changed the title of your question to reflect what you actually were asking, and I removed the "multithreading" tag because neither the question nor the answer has anything to do with threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not related to threading. You are trying to concatenate the string with int. Try change:

```
r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/?page='+args)
```

To:

```
r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/?page='+str(args))
```

Answer (score 2):

You would get the same error without multithreading if you call `run_the_command(1)`.

You're attempting to use `+` to concatenate a string and a number; you could either cast the number to a string with `str()`, or more modernly use an f-string to format it into your URL:

```
r = requests.get(f'https://coinmarketcap.com/?page={args}')
```

However, better yet, since you're using Requests, just use its parameter handling:

```
r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/', params={'page': args})
```

As an aside:

- you'll probably want to look into `multiprocessing` – starting 70 threads will likely not give you an appreciable performance boost due to the GIL.
- you might want to use Coinmarketcap's API instead of trying to scrape things. https://coinmarketcap.com/api/